# Extracting the nth character from a vector of strings

Tags: r, string

I have a row vector which looks like this:

```
1   118_o_m_n_a.jpg
2   122_m_f_h_a.jpg
3   152_y_f_n_a.jpg
4   160_y_m_h_a.jpg
5   083_o_m_a_a.jpg
```

how do I extract all entries in which, for instance, the 9th element (letter) is "n" (or "h", or "a" in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a regular expression that matches the start of a string (`"^")`, followed by 8 characters of any type (`".{8}"`), followed finally, in the 9th position, by the character `"n"`:

```
v <- c("118_o_m_n_a.jpg", "122_m_f_h_a.jpg", "152_y_f_n_a.jpg", 
       "160_y_m_h_a.jpg", "083_o_m_a_a.jpg")

## Find the indices of matching elements
grep("^.{8}n", v)
# [1] 1 3

## Return matching elements
grep("^.{8}n", v, value=TRUE)
# [1] "118_o_m_n_a.jpg" "152_y_f_n_a.jpg"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `substr` to extract the 9th letter:

```
substr(c("122_m_f_h_a.jpg", "152_y_f_n_a.jpg"), 9, 9)
[1] "h" "n"
```

Use `==` and subsetting for the rest of the task.